# How to choose random fish every second from the 6 classes of fish species and add to csv file if is caught?

Tags: python

I have created the classes of all 6 fishes species like:

**fish_species.py**

```
class AustrialianBass : 

  MAX_WEIGHT=4000 
  MAX_EATING_WEIGHT = 2500 
  NAME = 'Austrialian Bass'
  LATIN_NAME = 'Macquaria Novemaculeata'
  
  def __init__(self, weight):
    self.weight = weight
  
  def __str__(self):
    return '{} ({}) , weights {} kg'.format(self.NAME, self.LATIN_NAME, self.weight/1000)

  def is_good_eating(self): 
    if self.weight >= 500 and self.weight <= self.MAX_EATING_WEIGHT:
      return True

  
class ShortFinnedEel : 

  MAX_WEIGHT=3000
  MAX_EATING_WEIGHT = 3000
  NAME = 'Short Finned Eel'
  LATIN_NAME = 'Anguilla Australis'
  
  def __init__(self, weight):
    self.weight = weight
  
  def __str__(self):
    return '{} ({}) , weights {} kg'.format(self.NAME, self.LATIN_NAME, self.weight/1000)

  def is_good_eating(self): 
    if self.weight >= 500 and self.weight <= self.MAX_EATING_WEIGHT:
      return True

class GippslandPerch  : 

  MAX_WEIGHT=10,000
  MAX_EATING_WEIGHT = 6000
  NAME = 'Gippsland Perch '
  LATIN_NAME = 'Macquaria Colonorum'
  
  def __init__(self, weight):
    self.weight = weight
  
  def __str__(self):
    return '{} ({}) , weights {} kg'.format(self.NAME, self.LATIN_NAME, self.weight/1000)

  def is_good_eating(self): 
    if self.weight >= 500 and self.weight <= self.MAX_EATING_WEIGHT:
      return True

class EelTailedCatfish  : 

  MAX_WEIGHT=6800
  MAX_EATING_WEIGHT = 4000
  NAME = 'Eel Tailed Catfish '
  LATIN_NAME = 'Tandanus Tandanus'
  
  def __init__(self, weight):
    self.weight = weight
  
  def __str__(self):
    return '{} ({}) , weights {} kg'.format(self.NAME, self.LATIN_NAME, self.weight/1000)

  def is_good_eating(self): 
    if self.weight >= 500 and self.weight <= self.MAX_EATING_WEIGHT:
      return True
  

class GoldenPerch  : 

  MAX_WEIGHT=9000
  MAX_EATING_WEIGHT = 2000
  NAME = 'Golden perch '
  LATIN_NAME = 'Macquaria ambigua'
  
  def __init__(self, weight):
    self.weight = weight
  
  def __str__(self):
    return '{} ({}) , weights {} kg'.format(self.NAME, self.LATIN_NAME, self.weight/1000)

  def is_good_eating(self): 
    if self.weight >= 500 and self.weight <= self.MAX_EATING_WEIGHT:
      return True

class SouthernSaratoga  : 

  MAX_WEIGHT=4000
  MAX_EATING_WEIGHT = 2500
  NAME = 'Southern Saratoga '
  LATIN_NAME = 'Scleropages leichardti'
  
  def __init__(self, weight):
    self.weight = weight
  
  def __str__(self):
    return '{} ({}) , weights {} kg'.format(self.NAME, self.LATIN_NAME, self.weight/1000)

  def is_good_eating(self): 
    if self.weight >= 500 and self.weight <= self.MAX_EATING_WEIGHT:
      return True
```

The function simulates fishing process in the following way:
• Every second a random fish is “caught”. I.e., every second
the program randomly chooses one of the 6 fish species, then
randomly generates a weight within valid range (between 0 and
the species’ MAX_WEIGHT), and then creates the corresponding
fish object.
• If the created fish object is_good_eating, the object is
added to the basket (implemented as a list). Otherwise, the
fish is released, i.e., is not added to the basket.
• Once total weight of fishes in the basket exceeds 25

**fishing.py**

```
import random
import time
import fish_species
import pickle
fish = [fish_species.AustrialianBass(5000), fish_species.EelTailedCatfish(3500), fish_species.GippslandPerch(3300), fish_species.GoldenPerch(2880),fish_species.ShortFinnedEel(4000),fish_species.SouthernSaratoga(6000)]
item=[]
for i in range(6):
 #generates a random number between 10 and 20
 random_fish = random.randrange(1,6)
 fish.append(random_fish)
 print('fish added to the list.', fish)
 #pauses execution for 1 second
 time.sleep(1)
#opens/creates a binary file for writing
f = open('rand_fish','wb')
#save list l to the file f
pickle.dump(fish,f)
f.close()
#opens a binary file for reading
f1 = open('rand_fish','rb')
#load the object(list l) from the file f1
l1 = pickle.load(f1)
print(l1)
f1.close()
```

But i could get the desired result. When i run the program it shows output as:

[image]

Could anyone help to solve this problem plese?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The comments in the code don't match the code. You mentioned csv in the heading but never write to an csv file. GippslandPerch  has an tuple as MAX_WEIGHT not an integer.

Comment: Also, you create a list of six _fish_ objects, but then append to it some random _integers_. I suppose this is not what you want to do

Comment: Have a look at some tutorials for Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) in Python https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/  You have defined a bunch of classes for specific kinds of fish, where all the methods have identical code repeated. It would make sense to have a base `Fish` class and define just the changing parts (`MAX_WEIGHT` etc) on the specific sub-classes

Comment: You code in the question doesn't do what the text says it does, e.g. "If the created fish object is_good_eating, the object is added to the basket" ...nowhere is there a check for `is_good_eating`.  Also you do this `random_fish = random.randrange(1,6)` `fish.append(random_fish)` which is just adding random numbers to the fish list

Comment: Try breaking down the problem into smaller pieces and get each piece working by itself. For example _"the program randomly chooses one of the 6 fish species, then randomly generates a weight within valid range (between 0 and the species’ MAX_WEIGHT), and then creates the corresponding fish object"_... if you could get just this part working without the distraction of the other requirements you would be a lot further along than currently

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, creating 6 almost identical `class`es is not the best approach. But apart from that:

- I would separate a `list` of species from which to choose randomly the new fish, and a `list` of the fishes you caught. So it may be somethink like

```
species = [
    fish_species.AustrialianBass,
    fish_species.EelTailedCatfish,
    fish_species.GippslandPerch,
    fish_species.GoldenPerch,
    fish_species.ShortFinnedEel,
    fish_species.SouthernSaratoga
] #note we're not creating instances hence no parenthesis after class names
fishes = []
for i in range(6):
    #choose a random species (between 0 and 5)
    caught = species[random.randrange(0,6)]
    #create and append a fish with random weight
    fishes.append(caught(random.randint(0,caught.MAX_WEIGHT)))
```

- you defined a `__str__()` method, but when you `print` the whole `list` that method is not called. So instead `print` one fish at a time:

```
for f in fishes:
    print(f)
```